# css3 perspective with smooth text

Tags: html, css, perspective

my problem is quite simple actually.

i have 3d-container with text in it, like this:

```css
.container{
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quis debitis odio facere 
voluptate <br>  expedita non vel, accusamus eos, autem ipsam. Quis, in necessitatibus quod 
assumenda accusamus <br>  asperiores deleniti sint!
</div>
```

but as you can see, text quality is so low. how can i fix that?

i already tried this but it didn't work unfortunately:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

Comment: Can you include an image of how it is rendering on your machine, just to verify that a visitor is reproducing the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Try increasing the font size

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the font-size would help with the pixelation. But you will have to adjust the rotation degree accordingly

```css
.container{
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(15deg);
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quis debitis odio facere voluptate <br>  expedita non vel, accusamus eos, autem ipsam. Quis, in necessitatibus quod 
assumenda accusamus <br>  asperiores deleniti sint!
</div>
```